# Using KArchive with QT

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to use KArchive with my Qt application but I have been running to some problems.

https://wiki.qt.io/Karchive_on_windows - is the guide I'm using.

The errors below are the ones I have been getting:

```
Could not set up the appstream test. appstreamcli is missing.
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_LIBRARY LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET)
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * Qt5Network

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * ECM (required version >= 5.61.0), Extra CMake Modules., <https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdesupport/extra-cmake-modules>
 * Qt5Core

-- The following features have been disabled:

 * QCH, API documentation in QCH format (for e.g. Qt Assistant, Qt Creator & KDevelop)

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * LibLZMA, Support for xz compressed files and data streams, <http://tukaani.org/xz/>
   Support for xz compressed files and data streams

-- The following RECOMMENDED packages have not been found:

 * BZip2, Support for BZip2 compressed files and data streams, <https://sourceware.org/bzip2/>
   Support for BZip2 compressed files and data streams

-- The following REQUIRED packages have not been found:

 * ZLIB, Support for gzip compressed files and data streams, <http://www.zlib.net>
   Required by the core KDE libraries and some critical kioslaves

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FeatureSummary.cmake:457 (message):
  feature_summary() Error: REQUIRED package(s) are missing, aborting CMake
  run.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (feature_summary)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/tests
ZLIB_LIBRARY
    linked by target "KF5Archive" in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/src
    linked by target "kfiltertest" in directory C:/Users/emiol/OneDrive/Desktop/git/karchive/autotests

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Looks like you need to install a few dependencies..

Comment: I already have the zlib and the bzip2

Comment: "I already have the zlib and the bzip2" - Then, obviously, you haven't told CMake where you have them and they are not in the default locations where it looks for them.

Comment: Hmm, I am following this documentation https://wiki.qt.io/Karchive_on_windows . Can you tell me how to go about it

Comment: How does your setting of the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH looks on the command line? The documentation you cited has an invalid setting for this. If you query the history of the site you will find out it should read `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\kderoot;C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2012;C:\Users\emiol\OneDrive\Desktop\git\karchive\zlib;C:\Users\emiol\OneDrive\Desktop\git\karchive\bzip2` The path to KDE and Qt still need to be adapted. See https://wiki.qt.io/index.php?title=Karchive_on_windows&diff=5124&oldid=1145 for the original article